# This code always return $id but not $first_name

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PDO+Mysql where I am passing udid from a session and if the rowcount is greater than 0, I would like to fetch `id` from the table as well as `first_name`, which is the `fifth` column in the table.

The problem is id is always returned right but not the `first_name`, not sure why

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id= :udid");                     
$stmt->bindValue(':udid', $_SESSION['udid']);
$stmt->execute();

$id=$stmt->fetchColumn();
$first_name=$stmt->fetchColumn(5);
```

Comment: You should really name the columns you want to select and not use `select *`

Comment: @juergend I would like to return almost 9 columns out of the 10

Comment: What's wrong with fetching the row as an assoc array and using the field name to access it? Why do you need to use a number?

Comment: use $row =  $stmt->fetch(); it returns the entire row. $first_name = $row['first_name']

Comment: Selecting the columns individually is faster compared to selecting all of them with `*` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `fetch()` to fetch the entire row and then call each column by its name

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();
$id = $result['id'];
$name = $result['name'];
//and so on for all the columns
```

Comment: @yourcommonsense care to explain downvote? or just... its wrong, false, fail or whatever

Comment: @yourcommonsense is just here to downvote everything, it seems

Comment: Yes. it is called "frustration". Nothing personal though. Just while you're wasting your life looking for a duplicate, someone is sneaking in to answer a silly question. But I have to congratulate you - finally you managed to write an answer that is not wrong.

Comment: @YourCommonSense haha very funny